# Pass Form Values to Module in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Changing server connection with MySQL before proceeding to transaction

> Form1.vb

`server.text, username.text, password.text`

> Connection.vb (Module)

`retrieve the value of server, username and password to pass it to my connection string.`

I want to pass the value to the

```
        Try
            If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                strcon = "server=" + server.text + ";user=" + username.text + ";password=" + password.text + ";port=3306;database=db_system;sslmode=none; Convert Zero DateTime = true"
                Conn.ConnectionString = strcon
                Conn.Open()
                result = True
                Main.Show()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            result = False
        End Try
        Return result
    End Function
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference here (and never would make a difference under `Option Strict On`), but there is a separate string concatenation operator in VB, `&`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VB.NET, then calling the values of textboxes, it should end with `.Text`

```
"server=" + server.Text + ";user=" + username.Text + ";password=" + password.Text
```

You can create a function in the module like this:

```
Function DBValues (server As String, user As String, password As String) as String

'Do as you please with the values

End Function
```

Then in your form:

```
dbValues = DBValues(server.Text, username.Text, password.Text)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry for confusing, i mistype it. my problem is how to pass the value from form1 textboxes to public module function

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: If you've solved your code, kindly mark an answer or update us so other people can see the post and maybe could help them someday. Thank you! :)